# run SQL query in PHP based on checked boxes

Tags: php, sql

I am running this SQL Query in PHP:

```
$stmt = $pdo_conn->prepare("SELECT * from porting order by field(status, 'Submitted', 'Rejected', 'Cancelled', 'Accepted') ");
$stmt->execute(array());
$records = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

But i want to be able to add checkboxes to modify the query without refreshing the page

for example,

```
<input type="checkbox" name="status" value="Submitted" />
<input type="checkbox" name="status" value="Rejected" />
<input type="checkbox" name="status" value="Cancelled" />
<input type="checkbox" name="status" value="Accepted" />
```

so if the input with a value of 'Submitted' is checked the query will change to:

```
SELECT * from porting where status = 'Submitted'
```

and if both inputs with values 'Submitted' and 'Accepted' are checked, the query will be:

```
SELECT * from porting where status = 'Submitted' or status = 'Accepted'
```

Comment: You've told us what you want. Now tell us what you've tried.

Comment: What do you mean by "without refreshing the page"?

Comment: `order by field(status, 'Submitted', 'Rejected', 'Cancelled', 'Accepted')`?

Answer (score 2):

Your checkboxes should use array syntax

```
<input type="checkbox" name="status[]" value="Submitted" />
<input type="checkbox" name="status[]" value="Rejected" />
<input type="checkbox" name="status[]" value="Cancelled" />
<input type="checkbox" name="status[]" value="Accepted" />
```

From there, you [implode](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php).

```
$sql = "SELECT * from porting where status IN('".implode("', '", $_POST['status'])."')";
```

**WARNING: The SQL query above IS VULNERABLE TO [SQL INJECTION](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/601300/what-is-sql-injection)**, but it should get you on the right track.

Comment: Curious. How does this handle the `where status = 'Submitted' or status = 'Accepted'`? More specifically, the `or` clause. Does your `IN` clause do that?

Comment: @Fred-ii- I believe that this answer is taking the liberty of assuming that the use of `OR` is not strictly required and therefore `IN` may be a suitable replacement.

Comment: @PatrickQ Was just stating what the OP asks in the question *"and if both inputs with values 'Submitted' and 'Accepted' are checked, the query will be:

`SELECT * from porting where status = 'Submitted' or status = 'Accepted'`"*

Comment: @Fred-ii Yes "IN" is best choice here as it make your answer dynamic rather than specific. And also "IN" does same think as you think need in "OR".

Comment: @Pinu Thanks for clarifying that for me. I like understand how things work, cheers.

Answer (score 0):

```
$checkboxes = $_POST['status'];
if(count($checkboxes)) {
    $where_clause = ' where';
}
else {
    $where_clause = '';
}
foreach($checkboxes as $el) { $el = addslashes($el);
   $where_clause .= " status = '$el' or";
}
$where_clause = substr($where_clause, 0, -2);

$query = 'select * from porting' . $where_clause;
```

Finally, `$query` will contain a string like this:

```
select * from porting where status = 'Submitted' or status = 'Cancelled'
```

And you should use `name="status[]"` instead of `name="status"` if you want to send more than one values.